# Collada exporter doesn't export some polys when modifier order is changed

Tags: modifiers, collada

Suppose I have a boolean and then bevel modifier like so:

[image]

Then I export using the collada exporter with the "apply modifiers" option and I get this:

[image]

However if I reverse the order of the two modifiers:

[image]

Then the resulting mesh is missing polygons:

[image]

Am I using the exporter wrong or is there a bug in the exporter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in Blender 3.5.0 alpha.